# Rails, select_tag, :onchange => not ajax request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a select tag with :onchange which updates the page with relevant data, however, I don't want to do it with Ajax because it is messing up my navigation structure.

I want to use select_tag and when they its is changed it sends a regular HTML request which refreshes the entire page.

How can I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good solution:

[RJS: Ajaxified select_tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579855/rjs-ajaxified-selecttag)