# Rails - get database fields to update without having to click a submit button - possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, database, submit

I've got a dropdown list for users to select whether a task is completed or not. I want their changes to update the status on the database, without them having to click a submit button every time they make a change. Is this possible?

Basically, all tasks are marked as not complete by default, so when the user clicks the dropdown and changes it to complete, I want this to change on the database without them having to click a submit button.

Any help anyone could give would be great, thanks!

This is the code I have:

```
<%= form_for task do %>
    <td><%= select :task, :complete, [ ["Yes",2], ["Partly",1], ["No",0]], { :action => "update" } %></td>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several gems that utilize JSON requests to poll the models. I recommend watching [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing) video. Ryan goes into detail on how to use the gem to do in place editing on a page.

Answer (score 2):

try adding this:

```
:onchange => "this.form.submit();"
```

take a look at [RJS: Ajaxified select_tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579855/rjs-ajaxified-select-tag) for more detail how to use

Comment: Thanks - that has nearly worked - it has updated the database with the correct info, but the page reloads and still has 'Yes' in the box - how can I get it to display the actual contents of the field in the database?

Comment: `:selected => ...`
I think you need to change the first line to have access to your stored data. Something like `<%= form_for @task do |t| %>`. Then you could use `<% t.select ..., :selected => t.complete`.
Maybe it depends on your rails version

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with ajax. You can listen to the [onchange](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/SCR19) event on the select tag.

This is the best [ajax on rails](http://blog.madebydna.com/all/code/2011/12/05/ajax-in-rails-3.html) guide on the net imo, so maybe you can get some tips from it.